# Random y axis in Pandas catplot

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

Please see figure. [image]

I'm using `sns.catplot(x='Event', y='# Runs', hue='Code', data=df)` to plot this. I don't understand why the y-axis is all over the place.

Comment: Is `# Runs` being passed in as strings or ints/floats? And is this the order you're passing them from your df?

Comment: @G.Anderson: I don't understand. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If you call `df.dtypes` on your df, what is the dtype of the `# Runs` column?

Comment: It's object datatype.

Comment: You're passing in a list of strings, not a list of numbers. Seaborn can't sort those as if they're numeric, and just lists them on the axis in the order received. Try casting the column `astype('int')` and then passing it in.

Comment: When I try df['# Runs'] = df['# Runs'].astype('int'), I get 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194070/discussion-between-db18-and-g-anderson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in a list of strings, not a list of numbers. Seaborn can't sort those as if they're numeric, and just lists them on the axis in the order received. Try casting the column `astype('int')`

Since you have some blank strings in your data, you need to select those out somehow if you don't want them plotted, `df[df['# Runs']!='']` or similar, then cast the column to int as previously discussed, then try your plotting again. This should sort the axis correctly, without blank or `NaN` values